# Degree of polynomials describing projection of algebraic set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, elimination-theory, effective-results

Consider an algebraic subset $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined as the zero set of polynomials ${f_i}$ and the projection map $\pi: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ deleting the last entry.

By the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem, the image $\pi(V)$ is a semi-algebraic set. Is there a bound on the degree of the polynomials characterizing $\pi(V)$ in terms of the degrees of the polynomials $f_i$?

Comment: Your question pertains to effective bounds in classical elimination theory. I think the first such general bounds are due to Grete Hermann https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grete_Hermann you can start there and look up references to her work, to see what is currently known.

Comment: I didn't see the question is about $\mathbb{R}$ rather than the algebraically closed case $\mathbb{C}$ where I think one gets doubly exponential bounds. The real case, I think is harder, see the article by Saugata Basu in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00609687/document